# R, S Configuration and Branching - Which Path?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, stereochemistry

Which path do I take when we have a branched chiral center? None of the textbooks I've consulted adequately covers this or even provides an example problem in which there was branching.

[image]

Consider the above:

1) Chiral carbon with the following attachments H, an carboxylic acid group, a methyl group, and then the ring.

2) H gets the lowest priority.

3) The methyl group gets the second lowest priority since it has just one carbon and then hydrogens; the other paths have either more carbons or oxygens!

4) Between the carboxylic acid group and the path along the ring, we have an oxygen and a hydrogen going for the carboxylic acid group. But which path do I take? After comparing the carbon in the carboxylic acid group to the carbon on the ring, do I compare the double-bonded oxygen to the next carbon on the ring or the single-bonded oxygen? How does one choose in cases of branching such as these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No,  you have a carbon figuratively attached to 3 oxygen atoms vs.  a carbon figuratively attached to 3 carbon atoms; the former has higher priority.

Comment: Even if it would be only one Oxygen compared to a branched Carbon, the former will still have higher priority.

Answer (score 3):

As @ron mentioned $\ce{-CO_{2}H}$ has higher priority so the numeration given by @ADG in the fischer projection is incorrect because he assumes that the ring has higher priority than $\ce{-CO_{2}H}$. You can also think in the ring priority as $(C,C,C)$ and $\ce{-CO_{2}H}$ priority as $(C,O,O)$. As you may notice$(C,O,O)$ has higher priority than $(C,C,C)$ (the total atomic number of the substituent group in the first case is higher).
See the following figure:

[image]
([Source](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Organic_Chemistry/Chirality/Absolute_Configuration,_R-S_Sequence_Rules))

In this case I don't think you need to continue the path, but if that's the case you can see how it works in the figure.

Comment: The $\ce{CO2H}$ moiety should be thought of as $\ce{(C,O,O,O)}$ because the carbon is bonded via three bonds to oxygen.

Answer (score 1):

convert it to **fischer projection**:

[image: fischer projection]

you can see it is (**S**)
**Edit: Added Explanation**
Going according to atomic numbers.

> Atomic no.1

1.$\ce{H}$- lowest priority.

> Atomic no. 6

2.$\ce{CH3}$ - next priority.Has $\ce{H}[1]$
3.$\ce{C6H4..}$ - next priority. Has $\ce{C}[6]$
4.$\ce{COOH}$ - next priority.Has $\ce{O}[8]$